# Django allauth SocialAccount model's "extra_data" field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

SocialAccount model has the `extra_data` field in the table. And this model has a relation with the **User** table. when I am retrieving the User table, trying to add the `SocialAccount` into the `User` but having a problem...

**serializers.py**

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from allauth.socialaccount.models import SocialAccount
```

### UPDATED

I updated the **serializers.py** and now I can implement add the `extra_data` into `UserDisplaySerializer`.

```
class SocialAccountExtraDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = SocialAccount
    fields = ["extra_data"]
    depth = 1


class UserDisplaySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  extra_data_set = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

  class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ["username", "extra_data_set"]
    depth = 1

  def get_extra_data_set(self, instance):
    extra_data = instance.socialaccount_set.all()[0].extra_data
    return SocialAccountExtraDataSerializer(extra_data, many=True).data
```

BUT this time `extra_data` field comes with those **empty objects.** There are six objects like expected but empty?

[image]

How should I insert the **SocialAccount's** `extra_data` into `User` serializer as field smoothly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by not serializing the data before return.

```
def get_extra_data_set(self, instance):
    extra_data = instance.socialaccount_set.all()[0].extra_data
    # below serialize and return the data 
    return SocialAccountExtraDataSerializer(extra_data, many=True).data
```

Instead of above I just `return extra_field` directly.

```
def get_extra_data(self, instance):
    if instance.is_superuser is not True:
        extra_data = instance.socialaccount_set.all()[0].extra_data
        return extra_data
```